# CSS Check boxes issue with Mozilla Firefox Pseudo Elements

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, css-selectors

After i spent some quite time releasing how should i make personalised Check Boxes in a html form i made some nice check boxes for my form that they work as they should in Google Chrome however in Mozilla they Labels are not aligning with check boxes (and on IE). How comes this?

Below the css and html code

and the photos of the issue[image: Google Chrome Perfect]

and Mozilla [image: Not Peftect]

```
       <div class="field">
     
      <label>Type of Vecicle that you'd prefer</label>

      <div class="form-group row">
        
        <div class="col-sm-8 checkbox-wrapper">
         
          <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="severity_3" name="severity[]" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label mozilla" for="severity_3">Standar Cars</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="severity_3" name="severity[]" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label mozilla" for="severity_3">Bike</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="severity_3" name="severity[]" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label mozilla" for="severity_3">Van</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="severity_3" name="severity[]" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label mozilla" for="severity_3">Luxury CarS</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="severity_5" name="severity[]" value="5">
            <label class="form-check-label mozilla" for="severity_5">SUV</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

              </div>
```

and CSS

```
     input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      -moz-appearance:initial;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid #2699FB;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-appearance:initial;
}

input[type=checkbox]:hover:before {
    border:2px solid cyan;
    -moz-appearance:initial;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 6px;
    -moz-appearance:initial;
}

.form-check-label {
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    -moz-appearance:initial;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Hack to resolve this issue.

- `-moz` for Firefox
- `-ms` for Internet Explorer
- `-o` for Opera <= 12

Firefox example:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid #2699FB;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox]:hover:before {
    border:2px solid cyan;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 6px;
}

.form-check-label {
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
  input[type=checkbox] {
      -moz-appearance: initial;
      padding: 6px;
  }  

  .form-check-label {
      top:0px !important;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @-moz-document url-prefix() {  
  input[type=checkbox] {
      -moz-appearance: initial;
      padding: 6px;
  }  

When i am using the above parameter it messes with another Input properties that i have set up for textfields A Hide and show related .input-requirements when interacting with input

Edit: Actually i copy paste the whole code snippet of you and it works like a charm on Mozilla! Thank you so much!
However i am surprised how different Mozilla works even on fonts. On mozilla the text looks more bold thant google chrome version.